# Displaying multiple pages of a single file

Tags: javascript

I have a file that contains 50 rows. I need to display 10 rows at a time followed by the user's action like he requests for a page.. say page 2. where i display the next 10 rows.. I have called a function in js:

like:

```
setRow(rowID);
```

//id is the no from which rows are to be displayed.. i.e. 10 rows from rowId are to be displayed... it is called from an onclick event...

like this:

```
    <input type = "button" vlaue = "1" onclick = "setRow(1);
```

" >

```
function setRow(val id) {
    display 10 rows from id;
}
```

I tried using: document.get.....ById('').innerHTML... but that does not work..

How am i able to do that?

Comment: Your code example needs to clearer. When would like to call setRow? What is the id parameter? Is it the ID of the table, a row or something else? What did you want to use `document.get...ById` for and what did you expect to get by passing it an empty string?

Comment: are you stuck at getting 10 rows or displaying rows? where exactly are you stucked?

Comment: @Harry Joy.... I am stucj at getting the 10 rows from rowId...

Comment: please specify which file do you have .txt or .csv or word or pdf ?????????

Comment: Take a look: http://www.9lessons.info/2009/09/pagination-with-jquery-mysql-and-php.html

Comment: @Harry Joy: That is what i exactly wanted... even i Googled it but could not get... Thanx a lot...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you rows are in table with id='mytable'

You can use this jQuery script:

```
function setRow(iStart, iEnd)
{
  $('#mytable tr').each(function(i){
   if(i>=iStart && i<=iEnd) $(this).fadeIn();
   else $(this).hide();
  });
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/each/